# C# string contains all alphabetic characters of another string

Tags: c#, regex

I have two strings like this:

```
string longName = "PRODUCT MANAGER OFFICE";
string shortName = "P.M.O";
```

I want to validate if longName contains short name alphabetic characters (PMO).

But the short name may be like this:

- `string shortName = "PMO";`
- `string shortName = "pmo";`
- `string shortName = "pmoff";`

All of these short names contain `p, m, o, f` characters and these are also used in long name.

So I want to math string characters. How can I do this? Should I use regex or another way?

Comment: do you want to check characters of `shortName` present in `longName`.

Comment: You should know by now we need to see what you've tried first....

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar yes I want to check if shortName alphabetic charecters in longName. Not special charecters.

Comment: Do do you mean current *shortName* is not accepted?

Comment: Is "IGD" as a short name also valid? I, G, and D appear somewhere in _longName_ in your example. Or do you want to check for the first characters of each word in _longName_? Does the order matter, so is "O.M.P." also valid?

Comment: check my fiddler: I tried to solve your issue, but not fully by regex and as you are not showing us what you have tried so far, so NOT writing an answer https://dotnetfiddle.net/RLcpcw

Comment: Also, does `pmoff` suggests there should be at least two `f` chars in the long name? Also, is it case-sensitive?

Comment: All of short names in question are contains p,m,o f charecters and these are also used in long name.

Comment: What is login behind 'pmoff'?

Answer (score 1):

Regex is to heavy and slow for this simple simple task.

```
string longName = "PRODUCT MANAGER OFFICE";
string shortName = "P.M.O";

public bool ValidateStrings(string longName, string shortName)
{
  bool isValid = false;
  foreach (var character in shortName)
  {
    if (Char.IsLetter(character))
    {
      isValid = longName.Contains<char>(character);
      if (!isValid)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return isValid;
}
```

Comment: That might be what the OP is looking for yet the question lacks some details. Note the last `shortName` is `"pmoff"` which might indicate a valid long name must contain two `f` - your code will return true even if it contains only one `f`. Also, it's not clear from the question if the `shortName` chars should appear in the same order as in the `longName`, or if the search should be case sensitive or not.

Comment: @ZoharPeled He asked: How to determine if all chars that are contained in a first string are also contained in a second string. Character must be alphabetic to be relevant and tested. No rule regarding character count. There are a lot of possible restrictions or rules when comparing. As long nothing specific is said I give a general solution to a general problem.

Comment: I guess my answer also answers the question, doesn't it ? well, let's wait for OP's response

Comment: All of these short names are contains p,m,o f charecters and these are also used in long name.

Comment: That clarification came after my comment. As it is now, your answer seems to be correct. +1.

Comment: No, I think it's not exactly the same. But complicated. Instead of the split I would just check string[0] or string.FirstOrDefault(). But the main issue could be that you are checking only the first letter of a word rather than the entire string. The comparison must be valid as soon the string >contains< a letter. Position of that letter is irrelevant. No rule defined. So letter can be at the beginning or middle or at the end.

Comment: This is not a battle :)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy. Firstly, split the entire string into words :

```
 var text = "PRODUCT MANAGER OFFICE";
 string Shortform = "";
 var words = text.Split(' ').ToArray();
 foreach (string word in words)
 {
 ///Now in the loop, we will get the first character of each word and pass it to the ShortForm variable 
 Shortform = Shortform + word.Substring(0,1);
 }
```

So, now you have the short form as well, you can easily compare it with the given short form, sample :

```
 if(ShortForm == "abc")
 {
 }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
string str = "PRODUCT MANAGER OFFICE";
string shortname = "P.M.O";

string compareStr = "";            
string[] strArry = str.Split(' ');

foreach (string x in strArry)
{  
    if(x.Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        compareStr += x[0];
    }                
}
//Console.WriteLine(compareStr);

if(compareStr.Equals((shortname.Replace(".", string.Empty)), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("valid");
}
```

Demo 01: http://rextester.com/XVCG27648
Demo 02: http://rextester.com/GLSN75240
Demo 03: http://rextester.com/KVTN19152

The above method will not work if you enter 'PMOFF'. If you also want that, you can check the below method. Keep in mind that these both solutions only check the first character of all words. The second method will just ignore other characters.

```
string str = "PRODUCT MANAGER OFFICE";
string shortname = "P.M.OFF";

int count = 0;
string compareStr = "";            
string[] strArry = str.Split(' ');

foreach (string x in strArry)
{  
    if(x.Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        count++;
        compareStr += x[0];
    }                
}

if(compareStr.Equals((((compareStr + " ").Remove(count)).Replace(".", string.Empty)), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("valid");
}
```

Demo 04: http://rextester.com/EUIJ88090

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're matching up abbreviated names to proper names but without any real formatting (PRODUCT MANAGER OFFICE can be pmo or pmoff). So you need to be able to search each character for a match and stop searching when no match is found. You also need to keep track of the last position so that subsequent duplicate characters must match a new position. This makes the assumption that the order matters (pmo matches PRODUCT MANAGER OFFICE but won't match PRODUCT OFFICE MANAGER) and that all characters matter (pmoff matches PRODUCT MANAGER OFFICE but won't match PRODUCT MANAGER OF)

The following will work for all of your sample inputs and some additional test cases for longNames that I added. It's still not bulletproof though. As you can see with these requirements pmo will also match GYPSUM MINING OFFICE because of the P in the first word. Maybe you can tailor it to your needs.

```
static void Main()
{
    var longNames = new string[]
                    {
                        "PRODUCT MANAGER OFFICE",
                        "GYPSUM MINING OFFICE",
                        "The PRODUCTION of MANAGEMENT for OFFICES",
                        "PRODUCT PACKING PLANT",
                        "PRODUCT OFFICE MANAGER",
                        "PRODUCT MANAGER OF"
                    };
    string shortName = "P.M.Off";
    var charsToSearchFor = shortName.ToLower().Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray();

    foreach (var longName in longNames.Select(longName=>longName.ToLower()))
    {
        var allCharsFound = true;
        var lastMatchPosition = -1;

        foreach (var searchChar in charsToSearchFor)
        {
            var matchPosition = longName.IndexOf(searchChar, lastMatchPosition+1);
            if (matchPosition > lastMatchPosition)
            {
                lastMatchPosition = matchPosition;
            }
            else if (matchPosition == -1)
            {
                allCharsFound = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{longName} : {allCharsFound}");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Using P.M.Off as the shortName input, this will output:

```
PRODUCT MANAGER OFFICE : True
GYPSUM MINING OFFICE : True
The PRODUCTION of MANAGEMENT for OFFICES : True
PRODUCT PACKING PLANT : False
PRODUCT OFFICE MANAGER : False
PRODUCT MANAGER OF: False
```